# selenium webdriver- select an option from a drop down menu which gets populated through a js function

Tags: menu, drop-down-menu, webdriver

Menu is like

Access management
 |
 --search User
 |
 --create User

I have got into a situation from where there is no out. :( 
When I click on the menu link, the dropdown comes with another set of 3 links. Out of which I have to select link 2(Create User), but since on click of 'Access mgmt' there is a js function called which populates the submenu and thus I am unable to get any criteria to find that element and click on it. Please suggest a way to do it.

Access mgmt---js function called is clickToShowIt()
under JS script I can find the var defined as menu[0].node[1].name='Create User'

Comment: The fact that the menu is generated dynamically by javascript shouldn't matter, WebDriver should still be able to see the new entries in the DOM.  Could you paste the html of the menu after it is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least 2 options.
The preferable one (feel free to use [explicit waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits), if needed) is:

```
# python:

my_menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath(MY_MENU_XPATH)
my_menu.click()  # this click should execute `clickToShowIt()` for you.
my_option = my_menu.find_element_by_xpath(MY_OPTION_XPATH)
```

Or, if you can access the `clickToShowIt()` function from developer console:

```
browser.execute_script("clickToShowIt();")
my_option = browser.find_element_by_xpath(MY_OPTION_XPATH)
```